# How can I make this method use less memory?

Tags: java, regex

The following method is used to parse log files and find errors in them. It works fine until the number of errors run into the several million - 30 million to be specific. Then the server runs out of memory trying to run the application. I get a GC out of memory error. I can change the parameters to java so that it can use more memory, but I would like to optimise the code a bit first.

```
for (String logFile : fileList) {
        Map<String, Long> messageErrorCount = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        LOGGER.info("Mining data from: " + logFile);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String hostName = getHostName(logFile);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile));
            long errorCountPerFile = 0;
            String logLineStr;
            long firstErrorOccurance = 1;
            while ((logLineStr = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String errorResult = isErrorLine(logLineStr);
                if (errorResult != null) {
                    errorCountPerFile++;
                    if (messageErrorCount.containsKey(errorResult)) {
                        messageErrorCount.put(errorResult, messageErrorCount.get(errorResult) + 1);
                    } else {
                        messageErrorCount.put(errorResult, firstErrorOccurance);
                    }

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\s-");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(errorResult);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        String formattedError = matcher.group(1);
                        if (totalErrorMessages.containsKey(formattedError)) {
                            totalErrorMessages.put(formattedError, totalErrorMessages.get(formattedError) + 1);
                        } else {
                            totalErrorMessages.put(formattedError, firstErrorOccurance);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Need to add the file to list only if count is non zero.
            if (errorCountPerFile > 0) {
                String fileName = new File(logFile).getName();

                fileErrorMaps.put(fileName, messageErrorCount);
                putErrorLogRecord(hostName, fileName, errorCountPerFile, messageErrorCount);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("File operation failed: " + logFile);
            throw new ParserException("File operation failed: " + logFile, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("File operation failed: " + logFile);
                throw new ParserException("File operation failed: " + logFile, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the `isErrorLine` method:

```
public String isErrorLine(String logString) {
    if (isWhitelistedError(logString)) {
           return null;
    } else {
        Matcher matcher = ULOG_LINE_PATTERN_QUOTES.matcher(logString);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return (matcher.group(2) + " - " + matcher.group(3)).replace("\"", "");
        } 
        matcher = ULOG_LINE_PATTERN_ENDLINE.matcher(logString);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return (matcher.group(2) + " - " + matcher.group(3)).replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

These lines create new objects every time they are used:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\s-");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(errorResult);
```

Is there any better way of doing this method so it uses less memory?

Comment: Yes. move `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\s-");` outside the loop

Comment: You have 30 million errors in _one_ log? That indicates a massive problem elsewhere. Besides that, did you get and analize a heap dump to see what's using up the memory?

Comment: You are populating two maps, are you sure that they are updating existing keys instead of always adding new entries?

Comment: `messageErrorCount.containsKey(errorResult)` could be replaced by `messageErrorCount.get(errorResult) != null`  and you could keep a reference to the value in order to increment it when it is not null. That won't help with the memory problem but should reduce operations needed.

Comment: Note that using maps can have quite a huge memory impact, especially if using lots of them. If you can rearrange your data to use only a few maps it might be worthwile. Besides that you're storing `messageErrorCount` for every file (`fileErrorMaps.put(fileName, messageErrorCount);`) and thus that map can't be collected. Check whether you actually need `fileErrorMaps` at all or if so whether you need it all the time - maybe you could write the results to some file that you're processing separately in the end.

Comment: Are you reading the whole file in at one time? Why not read it from disk line by line? [Processing Large Files Efficeantly](http://www.java-success.com/processing-large-files-efficiently-java-part-1/) EDIT: If you can you should also move away from `new File` and use `Path` using the Java NIO file utilities and methods will also yield better results. [Legacy File I/O Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html)

Comment: Another thing you could optimize is string concatenation like `matcher.group(2) + " - " + matcher.group(3)`. Here the system will create 2 additional strings (note that strings are immutable) which takes up memory. Try using a `StringBuilder` instead (you could even try reusing it by making use of `delete(0, size())` etc.)

Comment: @Thomas: you are right - fileErrorMaps was not used anywhere. I have removed this and memory usage has reduced dramatically.